# Hex converter help - Python

Tags: python

I have this code that converts binary to hex

```
##  The Input part

l = raw_input('Input 8-bit number: ')
j = list(l)

##  Value Error part

t = [int(x) for x in j]
if len(t) != 8 or len([n for n in t if n not in (1, 0)]) != 0:
  raise ValueError('NOT 1 OR 0, or NOT CORRECT LENGTH')


##  The Conversion part

a = l[0]
b = l[1]
c = l[2]
d = l[3]
e = l[4]
f = l[5]
g = l[6]
h = l[7]

p = a+b+c+d
q = e+f+g+h

y = hex(int(p, 2))[2:]
z = hex(int(q, 2))[2:]

##  The Results part

print
print 'Results'
print 'Binary: ',l
print 'Hex: ',y+z
```

my whole conversion part is insanely long because whenever i try to convert a number that has 0000 in front of it it doesnt print the 0 and i need it to print the 0 is there a way to do this without doing the long process

Comment: Please tag all homework questions as homework.

Comment: Smartass answer would be: `from binascii import hexlify`. If I was to grade your homework, that would also give full marks.

Comment: There is builtin functions for this like @Jonathan M's answer. And, using `a=l[0], b=l[1]` seems bad, just use l[0], l[1] or better use a for loop. And anyway, `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = l` can replace 8 assignments. And you can replace 10 lines with: `p = sum(map(int, l[:4])); q = sum(map(int, l[4:]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print out a 2-digit hex number that is gotten from the binary input `l`. You can do that as follows:

```
print 'Hex: ', hex(int(l, 2))[2:].zfill(2)
```

Comment: nice but no way to get rid of x?? it gives me for example 0xf

Answer (score 1):

Skip all that coding.

First off, try `hex()`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hex

Then, check out `format()`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format

Comment: +1. If you're converting bytes to a hex string (instead of integers), you can also use base64.b16encode and base64.b16decode.

Comment: Ah, yes, there is a `homework` tag there. Good eye...Oh...wait...you put that in there. LOL!

Comment: I added the `homework` tag, it wasn't there when you answered.

Comment: how am i supposed to use the format function it keeps giving me syntax error on my comma

Comment: @tyim: what are you putting in for x? (and you're not actually putting in the square brackets, right? :)

Comment: so i went to your link said that format need specs so i clicked link to format specs and said i should put in x for the hex format

lol total noob

Answer (score 0):

```
print "%02x" % int(raw_input("Enter a number in binary: "), 2)
```